# Why is my python DataFrame performing so slowly

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm building an application that provides some very simple analysis on large datasets. These datasets are delivered in CSV files of 10 million + rows with about 30 columns. (I don't need many of the columns.)

Logic tells me that the entire file into a DataFrame should make it faster to access. But my computer says no.

I've tried loading in batches, as well as loading the entire files, then performing the functions in batches.

But the end result is that it is taking more than 10 times as long to perform the same process, than using a simple file read option.

Here is the DataFrame version:

```
def runProcess():
    global batchSize
    batchCount = 10
    if rowLimit < 0:
        with open(df_srcString) as f:
            rowCount = sum(1 for line in f)
        if batchSize < 0:
            batchSize = batchSize * -1
            runProc = readFileDf
        else:
            runProc = readFileDfBatch
        batchCount = int(rowCount / batchSize) + 1
    else:
        batchCount = int(rowLimit / batchSize) + 1
    for i in range(batchCount):
        result = runProc(batchSize, i)
        print(result)

def readFileDfBatch(batch, batchNo):
    sCount = 0
    lCount = 0
    jobStartTime = datetime.datetime.now()
    eof = False
    totalRowCount = 0

    startRow = batch * batchNo
    df_wf = pd.read_csv(df_srcString, sep='|', header=None, names=df_fldHeads.split(','), usecols=df_cols, dtype=str, nrows=batch, skiprows=startRow)
    for index, row in df_wf.iterrows():
        result = parseDfRow(row)
        totalRowCount = totalRowCount + 1
        if result == 1:
            sCount = sCount + 1
        elif result == 2:
            lCount = lCount + 1
    eof = batch > len(df_wf)
    if rowLimit >= 0:
        eof = (batch * batchNo >= rowLimit)
    jobEndTime = datetime.datetime.now()
    runTime = jobEndTime - jobStartTime
    return [batchNo, sCount, lCount, totalRowCount, runTime]

def parseDfRow(row):
#df_cols = ['ColumnA','ColumnB','ColumnC','ColumnD','ColumnE','ColumnF']
    status = 0
    s2 = getDate(row['ColumnB'])
    l2 = getDate(row['ColumnD'])
    gDate = datetime.date(1970,1,1)
    r1 = datetime.date(int(row['ColumnE'][1:5]),12,31)
    r2 = row['ColumnF']
    if len(r2) > 1:
        lastSeen = getLastDate(r2)
    else:
        lastSeen = r1
    status = False
    if s2 > lastSeen:
        status = 1
    elif l2 > lastSeen:
        status = 2
    return status
```

And here is the simple file reader version:

```
def readFileStd(rows, batch):
    print("Starting read: ")
    batchNo = 1
    global targetFile
    global totalCount
    global sCount
    global lCount
    targetFile = open(df_srcString, "r")
    eof = False
    while not eof:
        batchStartTime = datetime.datetime.now()
        eof = readBatch(batch)
        batchEndTime = datetime.datetime.now()
        runTime = batchEndTime - batchStartTime
        if rows > 0 and totalCount >= rows: break
        batchNo = batchNo + 1
    targetFile.close()
    return [batchNo, sCount, lCount, totalCount, runTime]

def readBatch(batch):
    global targetFile
    global totalCount
    rowNo = 1
    rowStr = targetFile.readline()
    while rowStr:
        parseRow(rowStr)
        totalCount = totalCount + 1
        if rowNo == batch: 
            return False
        rowStr = targetFile.readline()
        rowNo = rowNo + 1
    return True

    def parseRow(rowData):
    rd = rowData.split('|')
    s2 = getDate(rd[3])
    l2 = getDate(rd[5])
    gDate = datetime.date(1970,1,1)
    r1 = datetime.date(int(rd[23][1:5]),12,31)
    r2 = rd[24]
    if len(r2) > 1:
        lastSeen = getLastDate(r2)
    else:
        lastSeen = r1
    status = False
    if s2 > lastSeen:
        global sCount
        sCount = sCount + 1
        status = True
        gDate = s2
    elif l2 > lastSeen:
        global lCount
        lCount = lCount + 1
        gDate = s2
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Thanks for the useful comment @ManuValdés

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`iterrows` doesn't take advantage of vectorized operations. Most of the benefits of using `pandas` come from vectorized and parallel operations.

Replace `for index, row in df_wf.iterrows():` with `df_wf.apply(something, axis=1)` where `something` is a function that encapsulates the logic you needed from `iterrows`, and uses `numpy` vectorized operations.

Also if your `df` doesn't fit in memory such that you need to batch read, consider using `dask` or `spark` over `pandas`.

Further reading: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/enhancingperf.html

Comment: minor point: `DataFrame.apply` won't help with native vectorised loops or parallelisation…  it just iteratively applies the function to each row in turn.  this will probably be faster than using `iterrows` but not the orders of magnitude speedup from a native code

Comment: @SamMason apply does have some speedups, see the note in the docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html, but I tweaked my answer to account for your excellent point

Comment: I've added some examples using different approaches to my answer.  I was surprised by how little `apply` seems to help, I also thought it has fancy speedups/optimisations but it seems to be easily beaten with a simple iterator that I'd have thought would be slower

Comment: @SamMason yes, it's very dependent on what it is `apply`ing. Check out the further reading link in my answer. Also, have you tried much larger `df`s to see the difference in that case?

Comment: yes, I've read that doc and used Cython a few times…  I also started with a larger data frame, and made it **much** smaller when I realised how slow `iterrows` was!  running with more rows takes the expected linear difference, e.g. 10 million rows takes 1000 times as long for the last few examples (3.86 s using `apply`, 2.42 s for the last `for` loop)

Comment: just going through that doc and `[integrate_f_typed(*x) for x in zip(df['a'], df['b'], df['N'])]` is basically the same speed (1.12ms) as the fancy Cython `apply_integrate_f` version (1.19 ms with checks turned off)

Comment: @CharlesLandau the data easily fits into memory, which is why I thought it would be at least as fast as the file read operation. The main purpose of using the df is so that I can having to re-read the file, if I need to repeat an operation.

Comment: @SamMason you mean you weren't able to reproduce the performance on that page of the docs?

Comment: @JonnyCab conversely, if the data is small enough the overhead of creating a `df` could be exactly what is slowing you down...

Comment: @CharlesLandau I can reproduce the relative performance from the document OK, but I can also get basically equivalent performance to their unsafe Cython code with a much shorter & idiomatic vanilla Python function.  think I'll submit an issue on github

Comment: @CharlesLandau the CSV file I'm loading is about 2gb. I'm probably loading less than 20% of each row, but it's still close to 20 million rows. Is that small?
I was just assuming that reading the data from RAM, in any storage format, should be quicker than reading it from a disk.
Using apply saves about 10% on processing times but it's that's still not even close to the file reader option.

Comment: @JonnyCab it sounds like you might have a use case for Dask or Spark. Have you tried using the `low_memory` and/or `memory_map` kwargs in your `read_csv` calls?

Comment: Thanks @CharlesLandau I'm coming to the conclusion that Pandas just isn't suitable in this case. I'll take a look at the other options you've suggested.
I'll mark this as the answer, as it does at least tell me not to waste any more time with it.

Answer (score 1):

a few comments about your code:

- all those `global` variables are scaring me! what's wrong with passing parameters and returning state?
- you're not using any functionality from `Pandas`, creating a dataframe just to use it to do a dumb iteration over rows is causing it to do lots of unnecessary work
- the standard `csv` module (can be used with `delimiter='|'`) provides a much closer interface if this is really the best way you can to do this

this might be a better question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

just playing with performance of alternative ways of working row wise.  the take home from the below seems to be that working "row wise" is basically always slow with Pandas

start by creating a dataframe to test this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 1e6, (10_000, 2)))
df[1] = df[1].apply(str)
```

this takes 3.65 ms to create a dataframe with `int` and `str` columns.  next I try the `iterrows` approach:

```
tot = 0
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    tot += row[0] / 1e5 < len(row[1])
```

the aggregation is pretty dumb, I just wanted something that uses both columns.  it takes a scary long 903ms.  next I try iterating manually:

```
tot = 0
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    tot += df.loc[i, 0] / 1e5 < len(df.loc[i, 1])
```

which reduces this down to 408 ms.  next I try `apply`:

```
def fn(row):
    return row[0] / 1e5 < len(row[1])

sum(df.apply(fn, axis=1))
```

which is basically the same at 368 ms.  finally, I find some code that Pandas is happy with:

```
sum(df[0] / 1e5 < df[1].apply(len))
```

which takes 4.15 ms.  and another approach that occurred to me:

```
tot = 0
for a, b in zip(df[0], df[1]):
    tot += a / 1e5 < len(b)
```

which takes 2.78 ms.  while another variant:

```
tot = 0
for a, b in zip(df[0] / 1e5, df[1]):
    tot += a < len(b)
```

takes 2.29 ms.